# Proof verification: If $R$ is a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix, then $R-I$ singular iff $R=I$

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, determinant

Question: If $R$ is a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix, then $R-I$ is singular if and only if $R=I$ right?

Here is my solution:

Let $R=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta  & -\sin \theta\\ 
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$, where $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then
$$\det(R-I)= \left ( \cos\theta-1 \right )^2+\sin^2\theta=2-2\cos\theta=4\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$

So $\det(R-I)=0 \Leftrightarrow \sin\frac{\theta}{2}=0 \Leftrightarrow \theta=0$ (this is the only value in $[0,2\pi)$ such that it holds).

So $R-I$ is singular iff $R=I$, the $\theta=0$ rotation.

Comment: Yep, this works nicely! You could alternatively show that $1$ is only an eigenvalue of $R$ if $\theta = 0$. When else would a rotation matrix leave a non-zero vector with unchanged length and direction?

Comment: The title claim is not true in general, take $R={\rm diag}(0,1)$. Of course, this is not a rotation.

Comment: Only true for $2\times 2$ rotation matrices, not higher dimensions.

Comment: @stochastic Because suppose R is a rotation about line L in R^3, then any vector v on L is fixed and so Rv=v=>(R-I)v=0, where v is non-zero => R-I is singular in R^3?

Comment: @HIH that is correct.